# Why would eta expansion degrade the performance of fib?

Tags: haskell

I read [this article](https://wiki.haskell.org/Let_vs._Where) which says that the eta expansion would degrade performance of `fib`, like code below, the `fib1` would be much faster than other implementations. It explains that in the slower versions, the `fib'` would be redefined for every argument x. But I don't really get it. Could anyone give a more detailed explanation?

```
import System.Environment
import Control.Monad

main = do
    (mode:num:_) <- liftM (map read) getArgs
    case mode of
      1 -> print $ fib1 num
      2 -> print $ fib2 num
      3 -> print $ fib3 num
      4 -> print $ fib4 num

fib1 :: Int->Integer
fib1 = (map fib' [0..] !!)
  where fib' 0 = 1
        fib' 1 = 1
        fib' n = fib1 (n-1) + fib1 (n-2)
fib2 :: Int->Integer
fib2 x = map fib' [0..] !! x
  where fib' 0 = 1
        fib' 1 = 1
        fib' n = fib2 (n-1) + fib2 (n-2)
fib3 :: Int->Integer
fib3 = (map fib' [0..] !!)
  where fib' 0 = 1
        fib' 1 = 1
        fib' n = fib' (n-1) + fib' (n-2)
fib4 :: Int->Integer
fib4 x = map fib' [0..] !! x
  where fib' 0 = 1
        fib' 1 = 1
        fib' n = fib' (n-1) + fib' (n-2)
```

I tested the code above.

Compiled with `ghc --make fib.hs`, `fib1` is much faster than the others.
Compile with `ghc -O2 fib.hs`, `fib1` and `fib2` are of the same performance, while `fib3` and `fib4` are much slower.

It seems that with `-O2` flag, `fib2` is further optimized, so I tested with `ghc --make fib.hs -ddump-simpl` to see what is going on, and the generated code for the two functions are below

```
Rec {
fib1 [Occ=LoopBreaker] :: Int -> Integer
[GblId, Str=DmdType]
fib1 =
  !!
    @ Integer
    (map
       @ Int
       @ Integer
       (\ (ds_d10B :: Int) ->
          case ds_d10B of wild_X6 { GHC.Types.I# ds1_d10C ->
          case ds1_d10C of _ [Occ=Dead] {
            __DEFAULT ->
              + @ Integer
                GHC.Num.$fNumInteger
                (fib1 (- @ Int GHC.Num.$fNumInt wild_X6 (GHC.Types.I# 1)))
                (fib1 (- @ Int GHC.Num.$fNumInt wild_X6 (GHC.Types.I# 2)));
            0 -> __integer 1;
            1 -> __integer 1
          }
          })
       (enumFrom @ Int GHC.Enum.$fEnumInt (GHC.Types.I# 0)))
end Rec }

Rec {
fib2 [Occ=LoopBreaker] :: Int -> Integer
[GblId, Arity=1, Str=DmdType]
fib2 =
  \ (x_ay6 :: Int) ->
    !!
      @ Integer
      (map
         @ Int
         @ Integer
         (\ (ds_d10x :: Int) ->
            case ds_d10x of wild_X8 { GHC.Types.I# ds1_d10y ->
            case ds1_d10y of _ [Occ=Dead] {
              __DEFAULT ->
                + @ Integer
                  GHC.Num.$fNumInteger
                  (fib2 (- @ Int GHC.Num.$fNumInt wild_X8 (GHC.Types.I# 1)))
                  (fib2 (- @ Int GHC.Num.$fNumInt wild_X8 (GHC.Types.I# 2)));
              0 -> __integer 1;
              1 -> __integer 1
            }
            })
         (enumFrom @ Int GHC.Enum.$fEnumInt (GHC.Types.I# 0)))
      x_ay6
end Rec }
```

after read the code that `ghc -make -ddump-simpl fib.hs` generated, I write two new function to test it. Now compiled with `ghc --make fib.hs`, `fib5` is still much faster than `fib6`, I think these two functions would make it easier to analyze.

```
fib5 :: Int->Integer
fib5 = (!!) 
        (map (\n->
                case n of 
                  0 -> 1
                  1 -> 1
                  _ -> fib5 (n-1) + fib5 (n-2))
             [0..])
fib6 :: Int->Integer
fib6 = \x->
        (!!) (map (\n->
                case n of 
                  0 -> 1
                  1 -> 1
                  _ -> fib6 (n-1) + fib6 (n-2))
              [0..]) 
             x
```

Comment: the `let ... in ...` in the expanded version is an expression that get's evaluated for each `x` - so the function get's redefined (without the `x` Haskell will produce an function where it is only evaluated once in order to define the function - remember a function is just a value after all ;)) - is this better?

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the linked article, it seems that it's the difference between

```
fibs = let fibs' = ... in (\ x -> map fibs [0..] !! x)
```

verses

```
fibs = \ x -> let fibs' = ... in map fibs [0..] !! x
```

As you can see, in the first version `fibs'` is a global constant that never changes, and you're just indexing into that. In the second version, `fibs` is a function that constructs a "new", different `fibs'` for every value of `x`. And that's the performance difference.

Comment: In both cases, the definition of `fibs'` is independent of `x`. I still don't see a reason why it's necessarily impossible for a compiler to take advantage of that fact in case 2. Is there a fundamental reason for this that has to do with Haskell or is this just a quirk of GHC?